# How to update the ng-repeat view of a list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[This simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/213/) displays a list using `ng-repeat`. But if I change the list from outside the DOM (in this case, using a timer), the list view does not get updated.

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: You are making changes outside the angular scope thus the view does not get updated after the data is changed. You need to add a $watch to get look for changes made outside of the scope. However this might not be the best approach depending on a more complex implantation, but in your simple example it would work.

Comment: @JaredReeves can you elaborate? [My attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/217/) does not seem to work.

Comment: You mention that you are getting the data from the server side, how exactly are you getting this as it makes a difference, in how to properly implement/ fix this issue. I would use a service to get the data and then inject that service into the controller.

Comment: @JaredReeves It might be a push by the server, at a time that cannot be foreseen by the client.

Comment: If you can update your question with a more detailed example it would be easier to help you with the proper implementation

Comment: @JaredReeves not quite. The timeout already emulates a function that is being called on response to some data sent by the server. Judging from the answer below, the only way to do it though, is by keeping a reference to `$scope` and then calling `$apply()`?

Comment: manually calling the apply is an option(but only as a last resort), however it is better to use an angular service to retrieve data, as that what its intended purpose is. Look at [Services](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-services.html)

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I'll look into converting it to a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're calling setTimeout( fn ) from outside of Angular, the digest cycle doesn't know that the variable has been updated.

Try using Angular's `$timeout` service so that when the function is run, Angular will know to apply the digest cycle.

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/AELeK/)

**Edit: example using `$scope.$apply()`, in case `$timeout` is not what's being used.**

From the comments: "Yeah, you can run `if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()`. There is also `$scope.$digest` if you're just digesting the local scope. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g83VY)"

Code example from within controller:

```
$scope.lines = lines;
setTimeout(function() {
    lines.push({text: 'new text'});
    console.log('Line added: ' + lines.length);
    if ( !$scope.$$phase ) $scope.$apply();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Any solutions for when I am not using timers, but server-side (or other kinds of) updates?

Comment: Yeah, you can run `if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()`. There is also `$scope.$digest` if you're just digesting the local scope. Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/g83VY/

Comment: Is that future-safe? I heard that using `$$` variables should be avoided? Also, can you update your answer so I can mark it as correct? Can you by any chance, quickly compare it to using `$watch`?

Comment: Oh, and how do I get access to `$scope` outside my controller? E.g. when the server sends some stuff back?

Comment: Here's a fork which logs every time the `$scope.lines` variable is changed: http://jsfiddle.net/ntsK9/. If you're updating `$scope` from outside your controller, that's probably a "bad smell". You could theoretically pass it as an argument to a function, assign it to window scope, etc., but those are both bad practice and I recommend against them. Yes, avoid manipulating `$$` variables, but you can check them all you want.

Comment: It seems, I don't have any other choice than keeping a reference to `$scope`, if the server pushes the data, and the client cannot predict when?

Comment: Typically you'd be doing something like `$http.post( ajax_url, ajax_data ).then(function() { $scope.lines = [ 'new', 'array' ]; });` Once Angular completes that callback function, it knows to apply the digest cycle. That all happens within your controller. Say for example you updated data within a directive, then you wanted to apply that to the controller, you'd have to look at things like `scope.$parent`, isolate vs. shared scopes, etc., there are a lot of questions beyond this particular use-case.